# How to get the website image/logo with jsoup in Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to show a preview of URL with jsoup in android. 

But my concern now is that I can not decide which image to show in preview. What I want is to show the website image, such as the "F" logo for Facebook, "t" logo for Twitter. 

So, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You want to download image through Jsoup.. Your question is not clear

Comment: that is called favIcon, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for favIcon.

a favIcon might be in following ways-

like

```
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/image.ico" />
  </head>
```

or

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/image.png" />
</head>
```

or

```
<head>
    <meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image" />
</head>
```

For fist 2 types-

```
Connection con2=Jsoup.connect(url);
Document doc = con2.get();
Element e1=doc.head().select("link[href~=.*\\.(ico|png)]").first(); // example type 1 & 2 
String imageUrl1=e1.attr("href");
Element e2 = doc.head().select("meta[itemprop=image]").first(); //example type 3 
String imageUrl2=e2.attr("itemprop");
```

then load the imageUrl in ImageView.

Comment: Now the `Connection` with `con2.get()` will crash an app ?
Do you have any idea how to do with the new api?

Comment: please ask a separate question with your crash stack trace.